# My Link won't work after custom post delete (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom post type name **Blog**. So when click the link `[/index/blog/]` all custom post types show there.

Now I deleted the custom post type **Blog** and created a page and named it **"Blog"**. Now when I click the link it won't work. It won't show my page that I created.
Since I deleted custom post type Blog, shouldn't show my **page 'Blog'** at `[/index/blog/]`?

Comment: Please try using a tool like http://google.com/translate to make sure that what you write really reflects what you mean. What do you mean by "custom post type" and what behavior are you expecting ? Versus the one you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have created custom post type of name blog. Hence the slug `blog` is registered in database for custom post type. So it won't work for your page `blog`.

Edit the blog page from admin panel and check the `Permalink` which is just below the title. This is your link for `blog` page.

Comment: How can i delete slug from database

Comment: It will delete if you delete the post type and also completely remove it from trash.